# MySQL Using AND condition dosen't output data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple WHERE clause that should grab some rows from a MySQL table.

In this WHERE clause I have a AND condition but it doesn't output anything...

```
        $query = " 
        SELECT 
           *
        FROM homework
        WHERE 
            for_type_id = :group_id
            AND for_type_id = :class_id   
        ";

        $query_params = array(
        ':group_id' => $_SESSION["user"]["group_id"],
        ':class_id' => $_SESSION["user"]["class_id"]
        );  

        try 
        { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
        die($ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        $homework_data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

The reason why I use "for_type_id" two times in the SELECT part, is because a user in the database have a "group_id" and a "class_id" for diffrent types of homework, so I want to grab all the homework for one user, using "class_id" and "group_id".

And again, it dosen't output anything. No errors, no notices, nothing.

Any advise, please?

**Edit**

Fixed typo

Comment: Even with that Typo in there, no errors, notices, nothing? Not even with `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: You have a stray quotation mark in `die(...`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Nothing, I've turned on error reporting.

Comment: Where is your `session_start()` ?

Comment: How are you checking if anything is returned?  if you do something like `echo "<pre>" . print_r($homework_data,true) . "</pre>"`, does that show anything? Are you seeing any other output or is the page completely blank?

Comment: I don't get your explanation of `for_type_id`. Unless `group_id` and `class_id` are the same you'll get no results back.

Comment: To help debugging, I'd suggest looking at the data on the table (by removing the where clause) to see if it's your query or something else.

Comment: @Rizier123 In a file called "database.php" that connects to the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You state the for_type_id is used to grab all homework for one user.  If you use `AND` in your query, the returned rows must both be the group_id and class_id, which is almost certainly not possible.  I think you may need to use an `OR` statement

```
$query = " 
    SELECT 
       *
    FROM homework
    WHERE 
        for_type_id = :group_id
        OR for_type_id = :class_id   
    ";
```

That should return everything that is either group_id or class_id

Comment: Exactly how can you test for two values in a single column. Has to be "or" clause.